# "npm ERR! file bashcls" when executing npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm

i get this error, while trying to execute 'npm install' command in visual studio code:

[image]

What is this error about ?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: actually, i just finished installing vue-cli, and as you may know, by default npm runs an install command after that, and that's when i get this error. Should i upload my package.json file?